# Special Character boxtime

Tags: formatting, named-characters

In LaTeX, `\boxtimes` works as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

$\boxtimes$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to print this character in Mathematica? Simply using `ToExpression` returns nothing.

```
ToExpression["\\boxtime", TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

In a more general form, is there a way to use amssymbols in Mathematica?

Comment: The closest supported symbols are `\[CircleTimes]` and `\[CheckmarkedBox]`, and of course `\[EmptySquare]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

⊠ is [Unicode character U+22A0](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B22A0), and so we can input it in Mathematica by typing the following:

```
\:22A0
```

anywhere in a notebook.

This functionality is documented in [`tutorial/CharacterCodes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CharacterCodes.html).

As noted by Somos and in the comments to this answer, **the display of these characters is font-dependent**. The codepoint is valid, but if the font Mathematica is using doesn't have a glyph for the character, it will display as a small box with a question mark inside of it. You may need to play with your font settings to get the character to display correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The code `\:22A0` will produce the Unicode character for BOX TIMES but the font used for output **must** support the Unicode character and not all of them do, otherwise an empty "Box" (or something similar) will appear. For example, the font "Lucida Sans Unicode" displays the character correctly. In any case, this does **not** affect the internal string contents even if it is not displayed as you expected.

For another example, the code `ToCharacterCode["a⊠b"]` will return `{97, 8864, 98}` and the reverse code `FromCharacterCode[{97, 8864, 98}]` will return the original string.